# JsfCaptcha : show correct captcha value

Tags: jsf, captcha

I am using [JsfCaptcha](https://captcha.com/doc/java/examples/jsf-login-form-captcha-example.html) in an attempt to process offline captcha validation. While there is a method to validate "what the user entered matches what the captcha image has shown", I am having a hard time actually printing out what the server states is the right solution. I anticipated this being fairly easy to complete, but for the life of me, cannot figure it out. Here is how I am using the library:

```
import botdetect.web.jsf.JsfCaptcha; 
[...]

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MySampleBean implements Serializable {

    private JsfCaptcha captcha; 
    private String captchaCode;

    getters for above two fields
    [...]

    setters for above two fields
    [...]

    public boolean checkInputMatches() {
        if (!this.captcha.validate(captchaCode)) { 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method checkInputMatches() demonstrates how the library validates that the user has entered in the right captcha solution. What I'd want to do now is, for debugging purposes, is to log out what the solution was ( In the event that the user entered in the wrong value ). Potentially, something like this:

```
final String solution = captcha.getCorrectSolutionToCaptcha();
```

At first, I've taken a look through all of the public getters, but none of them are blatant in providing me the data I need. After trying all of them, I went down the [jdgui](http://java-decompiler.github.io/) route, where I decompiled the libraries and tried to hunt my way around to a solution / method that would give me this data.

Sadly, the JsfCaptcha class goes under 5-6 levels of base class extending, with a multitude of protected / private methods. Obviously, a very tedious and unnecessary hunt for something very simple.

Is it possible to print out the actual JsfCaptcha value that is being validated against?

Comment: @Kukeltje I've updated the question to be as detailed as possible now. Considering I am looking for a code solution, that does not seem obvious based on documentation, this is probably as detailed as I can get to seeking a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem with [javassist](http://www.javassist.org/), by modifying the generated bytecode of the [Botdetect library](https://captcha.com/doc/java/examples/jsf-login-form-captcha-example.html). I did this because I was **unable to find any getter method for accessing the actual captcha solution**. Obviously, this is not a clean solution, but it is a solution given that you just want to debug your code to determine why the code you entered does not match the code that the backend server has. For now, I'll consider this as a solution until there is a cleaner alternative requiring no bytecode manipulation. Here are the details on the version that I played with and got this to work:

```
botdetect-4.0.beta3.5jar
botdetect-jsf20-4.0.beta3.5.jar
botdetect-servlet-4.0.beta3.5.jar
```

When the checkInputMatches() method executes to validate the captcha, this structure is executed on the backend with respect to the mentioned jars:

```
Step 1: ( botdetect-jsf20-4.0.beta3.5.jar )
com.captcha.botdetect.web.jsf.JsfCaptcha ->
     public boolean validate(String paramString)

Step 2: ( botdetect-servlet-4.0.beta3.5.jar )
com.captcha.botdetect.web.servlet.Captcha ->
    public boolean validate(String paramString)

Step 3: ( botdetect-jsf20-4.0.beta3.5.jar )
com.captcha.botdetect.internal.core.CaptchaBase ->
    public boolean validate(String paramString1, String paramString2, ValidationAttemptOrigin paramValidationAttemptOrigin, boolean paramBoolean)

Step 4: ( botdetect-jsf20-4.0.beta3.5.jar )
com.captcha.botdetect.internal.core.captchacode.CodeCollection ->
    public final boolean a(String paramString1, String paramString2, Integer paramInteger, boolean paramBoolean, ValidationAttemptOrigin paramValidationAttemptOrigin)

Step 5: Observe $3 ( third argument from Step 4 ) to show the actual code.
```

Here is a photo using jdgui, through which I came to this conclusion:

[image]

With that in mind, here is how you can go about printing that value out when that code is executed using javassits ( I am using javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar , on Tomcat ) :

```
@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3121378662264771535L;
    private static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(CustomBean.class.getName());

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {

        try {
            final ClassPool classPool = new ClassPool(ClassPool.getDefault());
            classPool.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(this.getClass()));
            classPool.insertClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()));

            final CtClass codeCollectionClass = classPool
                .get("com.captcha.botdetect.internal.core.captchacode.CodeCollection");

            if (!codeCollectionClass.isFrozen()) {
                final CtMethod aMethod = codeCollectionClass.getDeclaredMethod("a",
                    new CtClass[] { classPool.get("java.lang.String"), classPool.get("java.lang.String"),
                            classPool.get("java.lang.Integer"), classPool.get("boolean"),
                            classPool.get("com.captcha.botdetect.internal.core."
                                    + "captchacode.validation.ValidationAttemptOrigin") });

                aMethod.insertAfter("System.out.println(\"Botdetect-DEBUG: entered-captcha: \" + "
                    + "$1 + \"; expected-captcha: \" + $3 + \";\" );");
                codeCollectionClass.toClass();
            } else {
                LOG.error("Frozen class : Unable to re-compile BotDetect for debugging.");
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOG.error("unable to modify the bot detect java code", e);
        }

    }

}
```

Given this input and challenge:

[image]

You get a message like this in your logs:

```
Botdetect-DEBUG: entered-captcha: U33aZ; expected-captcha: U49a6;
```